# I can't do a Github push, an error message always appears as shown in the picture

Tags: git, github

When I run `git push -u origin main` the result is error, as shown in the picture:

[image]

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2100907/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+remove+large+file+history

Answer (score 1):

You can't store files bigger than 100 MB in github.

You have 310.07 MB file vikiayaka/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-982053/chrome-linux/chrome

Please remove or add this file in .gitignore

Comment: Remove first. .gitignore will not forget about files that are already being tracked.

Comment: Presumably the folder `node_modules` has been committed by accident - this should be pulled in by a package manager, not committed.